# Why does it hang when I log on remotely and connect to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to connect to a server using

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MYRADSERVER -Credential
```

I'm then using

```
.\swsql.exe -u winty -p
```

It just hangs and doesn't prompt for a password.

If I do this locally on the machine it works a fine?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `swsql.exe`? Does the same behavior occur if you pass the password as a parameter instead of prompting for it? Why do you invoke the client remotely in the first place? The MySQL commandline client (as well as .Net Connector) can connect to remote database instances.

Comment: sorry that was not helpful.

I've tried passing the password as well and again it just hangs. But if i mstsc onto the server instead and run it. It works fine